# zxing android creating a list of scanned codes

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, zxing

So I am building an app which keeps track of items on loan to students. What I want to do is be able to scan the barcode on the student card, and scan the barcode on the item they are borrowing. This information should then be added to a "Loan" database table.

This should be able to be done multiple times, as there will be more than one student borrowing items at any one time. So when we are finished, the UI of the android app will have a list of student numbers retrieved from their student cards alongside the item they are borrowing.

I have embedded zxing into my app and I am already successfully scanning barcodes. I have just reached a point where I cannot think how to proceed with this next stage.

I think my main problem is that **onActivityResult** is retrieving the read data, and then it is being overwritten with every new barcode I scan. Is there any way I can scan multiple barcodes and save the data of each without overwriting?

From my Scan.java:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanningResult != null) {
    //we have a result
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();

        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);


    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

The table that loans information will be stored in. From DBHelper.java:

```
     private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ONLOAN = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ONLOAN + "("
        + COLUMN_ONLOAN_LOAN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COLUMN_ONLOAN_KIT_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_ONLOAN_BORROWER_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_ONLOAN_DATE_BORROWED + " DATE NOT NULL "
        + ");";
```

Comment: Post the code that you use to save data to your _Loan_ table as well as the `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: If you use the database to store results, why will the data be overwritten? Once a record inserted, the id will be automatically increased.

Comment: Because they are only saved to variables so far. I haven't got to the point of adding them to the database yet, because every time I scan something new, the variables are overwritten. The best way I can think to describe it as a library system - first you scan your card, then your book, then when you're finished, this information is added to the database. The database is not the problem - being able to scan more than one item in succession and storing all the information as individual variables is.